# Get a value from a json data object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object as follow:

[image: Returned json object]

How do I retrieve the value of column "ID_Entreprise".
I tried `console.log(data.rows[0].ID_Entreprise);`

but it gives me the following error:

`ModalForms.js:567 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Just a thought -- have you tried capitalizing `Data`?

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues:

1. You need to start with the variable that holds this object, not the data property inside the object.
2. The data property is called `Data`, not `data`. (Remember that case matters.)

Assuming your object is in the variable `jsonObject`, you would use:

```
jsonObject.Data.rows[0].ID_Entreprise
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It did work and the correct syntax turned out to be:

console.log(data.Data.rows[0].ID_Entreprise)

Comment: @Patrice, as a friendly reminder, the correct/polite thing to do on StackOverflow is accept the answer that best solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry,
Don't even know how to "accept answers". I had a headache registerring and even more when I want to log in and read check my posts.